# Непонятные символы при открытии файла с PHP-кодом

Tags: php

Что это такое, и как править этот код?

Это индексный файл *index.php*. Таким вот образом отображаются остальные файлы сайта.

[image]

Comment: @KoVadim я вас понял, спасибо! А как можно получить доступ к исходникам? Я просто понять не могу, как их интерпретатор обрабатывает.

Comment: А интрепретатор их обрабатывает просто. Он (php интерпретатор) видит @Zend и запускает свой модуль, который это дело декодирует. Но записано оно там в своем внутреннем языке. Можете просто считать, что это скомпилированный код.

Comment: Хороший вопрос, только переименуйте, пожалуйста, в названии "индексный файл" во что-нибудь, "index.php", например

Answer (score 6, accepted):

файл зашифрован zend'овский шифровщиком. Просто так править не получиться. Ищите оригинальные сорцы.

Но поговаривают, что можно найти декомпилятор этого дела. Но я этим не увлекался.